# Zend PHP Certification sample exam questions

Tags: php, certificate, zend-certification

I'm planing to approach Zend PHP (5.3) Certification Exam. Maybe anyone know where I can find sample exam questions?

Comment: Not really an answer but there are a couple of books on Amazon. However they are way out of date 2004/2005. There are some more recent study guides there but they won't cover 5.3 i don't think

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you can find something in the Study Guide? If you know everything in there the exam should be easy.

They sell the study guide in [their shop](http://shop.zend.com/en/php-certification/zend-php-certification-guide-pdf.html).

Comment: I have updated the link. They changed it to a paid-for e-book.

Comment: Yes i was about to edit the answer as well. Thanks for the update though.

Answer (score 8):

There are lot's of guide line about Zend PHP Certification. I think you take good over view about Zend. Here I am giving you some links:

[Zend Tutorial link 1](http://www.slideshare.net/carlosbuenosvinos/zend-php-53-demo-certification-test) : this link from zend "the php company",

[Zend second link 2](http://www.zend.com/en/services/certification/faq),

[Zend link 3](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/certification/zend/0672327090/practice-exam-questions/app01)

This provided by one of my teacher .I wish its may be helps you

Comment: one of the best link added By Mr. Emil Vikström.And his link is http://www.zend.com/topics/PHP-5-3-Study-Guide-v1.pdf .This is one of best guide line He suggest you